# Android: Canvas not clearing from outside onDraw

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing

I'm trying to draw a Bitmap on a Surface view like this:

```
 private void draw1() {
        if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            Log.i("View", "drawing...");
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            canvas.drawBitmap(playerShip.getBitmap(), 50, 50, paint);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        } else {
            Log.i("View", "surface is not valid");
        }
    }
```

But nothing appears. Just a black screen.

But if i add this:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

The bitmap is drawn.

Is it required that i clear the canvas, only from it's `onDraw()` method?

Also, i'm new to Android. Any advice on the style of writing, is welcome.

Comment: onDraw is called by system to draw frame in every 16 sec which is going to be displayed in your screen, so how could you clear canvas from any where else ? It will not work untill unless that method has been called from onDraw.

Comment: Thanks. I'm following a tutorial, but it's not mentioned about `onDraw` at all!